# Inapp Billing - Trial and grace period for test purchases

Tags: android, testing, in-app-billing, subscription, trial

I have released an **alpha** version of a new app to test an inapp **subscription**.
My test user installed the app on two devices and canceled the subscription a day later.

The Google Play app has recognized that cancelation on both devices.
After re-installing the app on one device, it can no longer be used without renewing the subscription. But on the other device, the app continues to work just fine.

I do understand that the **subscription period** is always one day with test purchases, but what about the **trial period** and the **grace period**? Is that also one day each or is that the real period set for the billing item?

Google's docs:
"Test subscription purchases recur daily, regardless of the product's subscription period."[1](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#test-purchases%7D)
[Testing In-app Billing][1](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#test-purchases%7D)

Here's a similar unanswered question:
[Android inapp billing subscriptions testing][2]

Comment: I think trial period is one day as well. Regarding your issue, can you try "clear data" for play store app from settings? Seems like the purchase info is cached and the results are not immediately available. But when you clear data for play store app, the info is refreshed.

Comment: <p>Thanks for your answer.</p><p>I think you are right, I took about 3 days until the app requested a purchase again. </p><p>I also think the Google Play Store doesn't has an inner clock, it always needs a server connection to recognize the expired or canceled subscription.</p>

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think you are right, I took about 3 days until the app requested a purchase again. I also think the Google Play Store app doesn't have an inner clock, it always needs a server connection to recognize the expired or canceled subscription. That is really annoying, I used a subscription instead of an once-off-payment to provide a trial period. If I remember correctly, there was a trial period for paid apps (2009: one day, 2010: 15 minutes). I think they abandoned that because of those casual games you just play to kill time waiting somewhere.